# how to open sqlite3 db through javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I am using https://github.com/kripken/sql.js this plugin for open sqlite db My js is

```
<script>
function print(text) {
  var element = document.getElementById('output');
  element.innerHTML = text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
}

var db = SQL.open('fixtures/db/development.sqlite');
 // Run a command in the database
function execute(commands) {
  try {
    var data = db.exec(commands.replace(/\n/g, '; '));
    print(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
    print(data);
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

and i am always getting this error "SQLite exception: 26, file is encrypted or is not a database". Is there any problem for opening sqlite file?

Answer (score 0):

Grant your web server access to the folder storing the SQLite file.

For example, if this is IIS, grant the user 'IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool' modify access to the SQLite database file or the containing folder. That user doesn't show up in user searches, but if you paste the name and click 'Check Names' when granting privileges using Windows Explorer it will allow the user to be selected.

If this is Apache, you'll need to consider chmod to change permissions.

For both web servers the file extension needs to be allowed. In IIS, you may need to add a mimetype for .sqlite.